# How do I use "String1.includes(String2)" in R shiny DataTable Javascript?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables

I'm very new to Javascript so maybe this has a very easy answer. 
I am trying to create a searchpane that allows me to filter out rows based on a string value in a column of a DataTable, specifically, whether the value includes a given string, similar to [this](http://live.datatables.net/nipucawa/1/edit) (the "includes(Edinburgh)" part of the middle searchpane), just in a shiny App, and I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work.
I already have a successfully working searchpane for filtering a number column by value, and the second searchpane is set up the same, just with a different return clause, yet only shows me an empty window for a searchpane.

The code is as below:

```
output$completeTable <- DT::renderDataTable ({
   datatable(  
        complete_Table, 
        options = list(
            dom = "Plfrtip",
            pageLength = 10, 
            columnDefs = list(  
                list(
                    searchPanes = list (
                        show = TRUE,
                        options = list(
                            list(
                                label = "big",
                                value = JS("function(rowData, rowIdx) { return (rowData[8] > 10000); }"
                                )
                            ),
                            list(
                                label = "small",
                                value = JS("function(rowData, rowIdx) { return (rowData[8] < 10000); }"
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    targets = 8 
                ),
                list(
                    searchPanes = list (
                        show = TRUE,
                        options = list(
                            list(
                                label = "All",
                                value = JS("function(rowData, rowIdx) { return rowData[3].includes('All'); }"
                                )
                            ),
                            list(
                                label = "Media",
                                value = JS("function(rowData, rowIdx) { return rowData[3].includes('Media'); }"
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ), 
                    targets = 3
                ),
                list(searchPanes = list(show = FALSE), targets = c(1,2,4:7,9:11) )
            ),
        ),              
        extensions = c('Select', 'SearchPanes')
    )
}, server = FALSE)
```

As I said, the first Searchpane works fine on its own, yet as soon as I add the second one the first one isn't visible/there anymore and the second one doesn't have any data or labels in it. I am assuming the problem is that I have to include the searchterms ("Media" and "All") in a different way, but I cannot figure out how.
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67439532/datatable-dt-shiny-r-custom-searchpane-from-comma-separated-string) answer and while it isn't exactly what I wanted it mostly solves my problem.

Comment: while the link in your answer might answer the question, the link can become broken over time. Therefore you should include some minimal information contained in the linked page in your answer.